# Android 4.4.2 fbioget_fscreeninfo failed using webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, ionic-framework

I'm currently using ionic library to create the UI of my app. The pages/js/css files are stored locally in assets folder.

They will be loaded into WebView component at start of the app.

I've been testing/developing it on my Nexus 5. And everything was okay, until I tested on a Samsung GS3. Below is the log

```
02-03 19:00:15.379: I/Crashlytics(8952): Initializing Crashlytics 1.1.13.29
02-03 19:00:15.389: D/APPPPPPP(8952): onCreate
02-03 19:00:15.419: V/WebViewChromium(8952): Binding Chromium to the background looper Looper (main, tid 1) {420a43e0}
02-03 19:00:15.419: I/chromium(8952): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
02-03 19:00:15.419: I/BrowserProcessMain(8952): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
02-03 19:00:15.459: W/Adreno-GSL(8952): <get_panel_settings:3802>: Android framework reported version 2. So, don't force ES30
02-03 19:00:15.459: W/chromium(8952): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
02-03 19:00:15.459: I/Adreno-EGL(8952): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.00.007.018_msm8960_KK_2.7_RB1_CL3869936_release_AU (CL3869936)
02-03 19:00:15.459: I/Adreno-EGL(8952): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
02-03 19:00:15.459: I/Adreno-EGL(8952): Build Date: 12/09/13 Mon
02-03 19:00:15.459: I/Adreno-EGL(8952): Local Branch: mybranch2092625
02-03 19:00:15.459: I/Adreno-EGL(8952): Remote Branch: quic/kk_2.7_rb1.15
02-03 19:00:15.459: I/Adreno-EGL(8952): Local Patches: NONE
02-03 19:00:15.459: I/Adreno-EGL(8952): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.00.007.018 +  NOTHING
02-03 19:00:15.599: D/APPPPPP(8952): onStart
02-03 19:00:15.599: D/APPPPPP(8952): onResume
02-03 19:00:15.689: D/OpenGLRenderer(8952): Enabling debug mode 0
02-03 19:00:15.699: W/AwContents(8952): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
02-03 19:00:15.749: W/AwContents(8952): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
02-03 19:00:15.829: I/chromium(8952): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
02-03 19:00:15.909: I/chromium(8952): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
02-03 19:00:15.929: E/qdutils(8952): FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO failed
02-03 19:00:15.929: E/qdmemalloc(8952): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
02-03 19:00:15.929: E/qdmemalloc(8952):  
02-03 19:00:15.929: E/qdmemalloc(8952): heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
02-03 19:00:15.929: E/qdmemalloc(8952):  
02-03 19:00:15.929: E/qdmemalloc(8952): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
02-03 19:00:15.929: E/qdmemalloc(8952):  
02-03 19:00:15.929: E/qdmemalloc(8952): heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
02-03 19:00:15.929: E/qdmemalloc(8952):  
02-03 19:00:15.929: E/qdmemalloc(8952): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
02-03 19:00:15.929: E/qdmemalloc(8952):  
02-03 19:00:15.929: E/qdmemalloc(8952): heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
02-03 19:00:15.929: E/qdmemalloc(8952):  
02-03 19:00:15.929: E/qdmemalloc(8952): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
02-03 19:00:15.929: E/qdmemalloc(8952):  
02-03 19:00:15.939: E/qdmemalloc(8952): heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
02-03 19:00:15.939: E/qdmemalloc(8952):  
02-03 19:00:15.939: E/qdmemalloc(8952): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
02-03 19:00:15.939: E/qdmemalloc(8952):  
02-03 19:00:15.939: E/qdmemalloc(8952): heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
02-03 19:00:15.939: E/qdmemalloc(8952):  
02-03 19:00:15.939: E/qdmemalloc(8952): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
02-03 19:00:15.939: E/qdmemalloc(8952):  
02-03 19:00:15.939: E/qdmemalloc(8952): heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
02-03 19:00:15.939: E/qdmemalloc(8952):  
02-03 19:00:15.939: E/qdmemalloc(8952): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
02-03 19:00:15.939: E/qdmemalloc(8952):  
02-03 19:00:15.939: E/qdmemalloc(8952): heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
02-03 19:00:15.939: E/qdmemalloc(8952):  
02-03 19:00:15.949: E/qdmemalloc(8952): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
02-03 19:00:15.949: E/qdmemalloc(8952):  
02-03 19:00:15.949: E/qdmemalloc(8952): heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
02-03 19:00:15.949: E/qdmemalloc(8952):  
02-03 19:00:15.949: E/qdmemalloc(8952): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
02-03 19:00:15.949: E/qdmemalloc(8952):  
02-03 19:00:15.949: E/qdmemalloc(8952): heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
02-03 19:00:15.949: E/qdmemalloc(8952):  
02-03 19:00:17.691: I/X509Util(8952): Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
02-03 19:00:18.312: W/UnimplementedWebViewApi(8952): Unimplemented WebView method onKeyDown called from: android.webkit.WebView.onKeyDown(WebView.java:2182)
02-03 19:00:18.412: D/APPPPPP(8952): onPause
02-03 19:00:18.622: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8952): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
02-03 19:00:18.812: I/chromium(8952): [INFO:CONSOLE(133)] "Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.6/$injector/unpr?p0=%24cookiesProvider%20%3C-%20%24cookies%20%3C-%20LoginCtrl
02-03 19:00:18.812: I/chromium(8952):     at Error (<anonymous>)
02-03 19:00:18.812: I/chromium(8952):     at file:///android_asset/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:37:416
02-03 19:00:18.812: I/chromium(8952):     at file:///android_asset/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:69:232
02-03 19:00:18.812: I/chromium(8952):     at Object.d [as get] (file:///android_asset/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:67:238)
02-03 19:00:18.812: I/chromium(8952):     at file:///android_asset/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:69:306
02-03 19:00:18.812: I/chromium(8952):     at d (file:///android_asset/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:67:238)
02-03 19:00:18.812: I/chromium(8952):     at e (file:///android_asset/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:67:497)
02-03 19:00:18.812: I/chromium(8952):     at Object.instantiate (file:///android_asset/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:68:130)
02-03 19:00:18.812: I/chromium(8952):     at file:///android_asset/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:107:195
02-03 19:00:18.812: I/chromium(8952):     at w.appendViewElement (file:///android_asset/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:384:24465)", source: file:///android_asset/js/ionic.bundle.min.js (133)
02-03 19:00:19.133: D/APPPPPP(8952): onStop
02-03 19:00:19.133: D/APPPPPP(8952): onDestroy
```

Comment: Two questions: 1) Have you try disabling hw acceleration? (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html); and 2) What exactly happens to your app -- does it display anything, or doesn't, or it crashes, or what?